# Java web app: pulling data out of database according to locales

Tags: java, database, internationalization

I am doing a Spring web application, but I feel this question is not framework-specific.

I have a HTML select list that has about 30 values. The web application needs to have interfaces for four languages. And thus for each language, the HTML select list needs to display translated text for the same list of values.

I could hard-code the list for the four languages with the JSP page and use conditionals to display the list with correct language. But I feel this approach is not easy to maintain and does not scale well, because the list may change constantly. And when the list is updated, the web app cannot be stopped.

I could also use Spring's message mechanism and property files to display the list, which appears suffer the same maintainability and scalability issues.

Another approach I am considering is to have all the list stored in the database and pull the list with the right language according to locales. I am not sure how to proceed with this approach in terms of design of classes and tables. Does anyone know of any similar work? Or any ideas?

Thanks for any input!

Cheers.

Comment: This is what property bundles were made for. Do a google search for 'jsf resource bundle'.

Comment: I am aware of the property bundles approach, which I already mentioned in my post.

Comment: Didn't realize that's what you meant by "Spring's message mechanism" (your recent update makes it clear). What are the maintainability and scalability issues in the resource bundle method as you see it?

Comment: Adding, modifying, and deleting entries in the list involves manual edits of the JSP page. In the case of dynamic list, the property bundles approach is going to be completely useless. Thanks!

Comment: These updates do not require any updating of the jsp pages. But only of the properties files. They may require reloading the properties files (which may require restarting your app).

Comment: "which may require restarting your app" ---thanks for mentioning this. I do want to avoid this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to go the database route, then I'd suggest a table with 4 columns:

```
locale: (stuff like "en_US", and "fr_CA")
group_name: (whatever they are grouped by: "random-select-widget")
value: (text value: "random selection")
order: (integer order that it should appear in the list: 0)
```

Compound primary key would be (locale,group_id,order). These could be made into integers by using tables of (locale_id,locale_name) and (group_id,group_name) if you feel the need.

Your classes could be simple Hibernate entities using `NamedQuery`s taking `:locale` and `:group_name` parameters to return an ordered `List` from the `EntityManager`.